# Adding layer to scene DOES NOT work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am facing what seems to be pretty straightforward: I want to add a layer to my scene, but somehow, the program does not show the layer at all! What is wrong ?

**HelloWorldLayer.m**

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{

    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    PlayingField *layer2 = [PlayingField node];
    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild:layer2];
    [scene addChild: layer];


    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

**PlayingField.h** is imported and inherits from `CCLayer`.

```
-(id) init{

    if ((self = [super init])){
        NSLog(@"entering init of PlayingField layer");

        //adding a bunch of Sprites
        }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Is there any visible element into your PlayingField?! Is your HelloWorldLayer transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one thing that you need to check, else code is fine.

If you have, something like that in your appdidfinishinglaunch method,

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector] runwithScene:[HellowordLayer node]];
```

replace with,

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector] runwithScene:[HellowordLayer scene]];
```

Comment: [HellowordLayer node] will return Helloworld layer only. while, [Helloworldlayer scene] will return scene,with adding "helloworld layer" and "otherlayer" ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:
[scene addChild:layer2 z:2];
[scene addChild: layer z:1];

or
[scene addChild:layer2];

or
[scene addChild: layer];
[scene addChild:layer2];